# WebStorm debugger does not attach on first time

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

When debugging a Node.js script with WebStorm, this is what my script looks like (windows):

```
"debug": "npm run build && node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% ./dist/server.js"
```

In the console I can see that `npm run build` executes as usually with success. Then there is a red message that states the following

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51311/0064d764-16b8-4b45-bdff-5a1732e9ee62
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

I can wait as long as I want - WebStorm won't attach and the `./dist/server.js` script is never executed. When I stop execution and re-run the script, it succeeds and the debugger attaches.

[image: Run configuration]
[image: Console output]

Comment: can you try updating to 2018.2.1 (released yesterday)? It includes some improvements in this area

Comment: I just updated a minute ago. Now running `WebStorm 2018.2.1, Build #WS-182.3911.37, built on August 7, 2018` and the issue seems to be resolved. I will report back if the problem occurs again

Comment: @lena the problem is still here :(

Comment: I'd need a project that shows it up then - the issue is not repeatable for me in 2018.2.1